# MOS working point in a differential analog mixer

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, cmos, differential, mixer

let's consider this simple configuration of a balanced differential mixer (analog multiplier):

[image]

I have understood that the local oscillator is generally a high signal, while the radio-frequency signal is small. Can you explain me in which region do MN1 and MN2 work? Are they switched from OFF and Triode region, or are they used in saturation?

Comment: the thing says "switching stage" right next to it... Btw, this is not a classical differential mixer at all, this is a chopper / switching mixer. Also, it's not balanced: the RF is fed in as an unbalanced signal.

Comment: (test for unbalancedness is whether RF or LO frequency appear at the output; they do.)

Comment: From what I know, a balanced mixer does not have multiple harmonics of RF and LO. So this is balanced. A mixer without also RF and LO, is double balanced.

Answer (score 0):

MN1 & MN2 can be viewed as switches, with their gate driving signals large enough to have them toggle between **open-circuit** and **short-circuit**. **Short-circuit** would actually be the on-state channel resistance \$R_{ds}\$.

Many mixers are run with MN1 & MN2 as alternately saturated switches, but it need not be so. Those two upper MOSfets can be biased in their linear region with their gates driven by a smaller sinusoidal L.O. signals. If done so, mixer gain is less, and MOSfets can contribute to a higher noise figure. The advantage is far fewer spurious mixer products at the I.F. output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOwpKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>